# How to get the date for the previous month which are closed in the current month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Iam using SSRS Report builder application to create BI Report for my System which is tracking the numbers of incidents logged and closed based on each month.

the below is the table which i need to create the query

```
Month      Logged  Received  Closed  Remaining
January    200     220       150     70
February   150     220       200     20
March      110     130       100     30
April      200     230       200     30
```

and each column define as follow:

Logged= Open Incident in the Current Month for example open from 1/1/2014 to 31/1/2014 (Contain only the current month data )

Received = Logged incident+ the remaining from the previous months which are still open not close for example the month febreuary will be 150 for the current moth+70 from previous month remaining will give me total 220 which is received.

Closed= incident which are opened in the current month and closed in the current month + the remaining from the previous month which closed in this month

Remaining= Received – closed

the code which i used is not giving me the close incident for the previous months also its only giving me which were closed in the current month

the below is the code which i used for my query:

```
SELECT  group_id, YEAR(Opendate) AS Year, MONTH(Opendate) AS Month,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Month(Closedate) = Month(Opendate)
            AND Month(closedate)> Month (opendate) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS closed, 
        COUNT(*) AS Logged, 
FROM    Incidents
WHERE   (Opendate >= @YearStart) AND (Opendate <= @YearEnd)
GROUP BY YEAR(Opendate), MONTH(Opendate), group_id
ORDER BY Year, Month,group_id
```

Logged is working fine the closed, Received and remaining i am stuck on it.

---

I tried to use `Union` and got the Logged and Closed Data

```
Select count(*) logged,year(opendate) as year1,MONTH(opendate) as 
month1,'Logged' as status1
From Incidents 
where opendate is not null 
GROUP BY year(opendate),MONTH(opendate)
UNION 
Select count(*) closed,year(Closedate) as year1,MONTH(Closedate) as 
month1,'All_Closed' as status1
From Incidents 
where Closedate is not null
GROUP BY year(Closedate),MONTH(Closedate)
UNION 
Select count(*) Remaining,year(opendate) as year1,MONTH(opendate) as 
month1,'Current_Month_Not_Closed' as status1
From Incidents 
where Month(Closedate) > MONTH(Opendate)
GROUP BY year(opendate),MONTH(opendate)
UNION 
Select count(*) Month_Closed,year(opendate) as year1,MONTH(opendate) as 
month1,'Current_Month_Close' as status1
From Incidents 
where MONTH(Closedate) = MONTH(Opendate)  
GROUP BY year(opendate),MONTH(opendate)
order by year1,month1
```

the data which I received are as follow:

```
logged | year1 | month1 | status1
-------+-------+--------+-------------------------
  1093 |  2014 |      1 | Logged
  1089 |  2014 |      1 | All_Closed
   997 |  2014 |      1 | Current_Month_Close
    96 |  2014 |      1 | Current_Month_Not_Closed
  1176 |  2014 |      2 | Logged
  1176 |  2014 |      2 | All_Closed
    91 |  2014 |      2 | Current_Month_Not_Closed
  1085 |  2014 |      2 | Current_Month_Close
  1340 |  2014 |      3 | Logged
  1327 |  2014 |      3 | All_Closed
   107 |  2014 |      3 | Current_Month_Not_Closed
  1232 |  2014 |      3 | Current_Month_Close
   116 |  2014 |      4 | Current_Month_Not_Closed
  1320 |  2014 |      4 | Current_Month_Close
  1424 |  2014 |      4 | All_Closed
  1441 |  2014 |      4 | Logged
  1167 |  2014 |      5 | Current_Month_Close
   105 |  2014 |      5 | Current_Month_Not_Closed
  1277 |  2014 |      5 | Logged
  1283 |  2014 |      5 | All_Closed
```

Comment: i will try and will update you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a reliable data a calendar table as anchor can help, and is needed in case the tickets can be alive for months from their opening date or there can be a month without ticket created.

For example with the fake data

```
CREATE TABLE Incidents (
  id int identity(1, 1)
, group_id nvarchar(100)
, Opendate Datetime
, Closedate Datetime
)

INSERT INTO Incidents
VALUES ('Service Desk', '20140107', '20140120')
     , ('Service Desk', '20140117', '20140123')
     , ('Service Desk', '20140127', '20140313')
     , ('Service Desk', '20140310', '')
-- from an OP comment the open tickets have the Closedate '' (1900-01-01)
```

without a calendar table (or a temp, or a CTE) there is no way to add february in the resultset, even if the third record is both "Received" and "Remaining" in that month.

To create a calendar there are several way, in this case we need the some information about months but nothing about the days, so those are not generated.

```
declare @YearStart date = '20140101'
declare @YearEnd date = '20140430'

;WITH D(N) AS (
          SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 
UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
)
SELECT EOM
     = DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(M, u.N + 10 * t.N + 1
             , DATEADD(Y, DATEDIFF(Y, 0, @YearStart), 0)))
     , pMonth = u.N + 10 * t.N
FROM   D u
       CROSS JOIN D t
WHERE  u.N + 10 * t.N <= DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart, @YearEnd)
```

Here `EOM` is the date of the end of the month, it'll be used to check if the incidents are closed in the month and `pMonth` is the progressive month starting from @YearStart.

Now we need to prepare the data in the incident table to be used

```
SELECT ID
     , OpenDate
     , Closedate = COALESCE(NULLIF(Closedate, ''), '99991231')
     , pOpenDate = DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart, OpenDate)
     , pClosedate = DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart
                  , COALESCE(NULLIF(Closedate, ''), '99991231'))
FROM   Incidents
```

the `Closedate` need to always have a value  higher than the OpenDate, for this is used the constant date `9999-12-31`, `pOpenDate` and `pClosedate`, as `pMonth` before, are the progressive month starting from @YearStart respectively of `OpenDate` and `Closedate`.

Putting those togheter it's possible to create the main query

```
declare @YearStart date = '20140101'
declare @YearEnd date = '20140430'

;WITH D(N) AS (
          SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 
UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
), CM AS (
  SELECT EOM
       = DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(M, u.N + 10 * t.N + 1
               , DATEADD(Y, DATEDIFF(Y, 0, @YearStart), 0)))
       , pMonth = u.N + 10 * t.N
  FROM   D u
         CROSS JOIN D t
  WHERE  u.N + 10 * t.N <= DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart, @YearEnd)
), I AS (
  SELECT ID
       , OpenDate
       , Closedate = COALESCE(NULLIF(Closedate, ''), '99991231')
       , pOpenDate = DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart, OpenDate)
       , pClosedate = DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart
                    , COALESCE(NULLIF(Closedate, ''), '99991231'))
  FROM   Incidents
)
SELECT MONTH(CM.EOM) [Month]
     , Logged = SUM(CASE WHEN pOpenDate = pMonth 
                         THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                    END)
     , Received = Count(i.id)
     , Closed = SUM(CASE WHEN pClosedate = pMonth
                          AND i.Closedate < CM.EOM 
                         THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                    END)
     , Remaining = SUM(CASE WHEN i.Closedate > CM.EOM
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 
                       END)
FROM   CM
       INNER JOIN I ON CM.pMonth
                    BETWEEN i.pOpenDate AND i.pClosedate
WHERE  CM.EOM <= @YearEnd
GROUP BY CM.EOM
ORDER BY CM.EOM
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc2ff/29)</kbd>

using a `JOIN` to get the month from the calendar table between `@YearStart` and `@YearEnd` and all the incident alive in the month. Their attribute are calculated with the `CASE` logic, in case of `Received` if a ticket is alive it's received so no logic is needed.

All the `CASE` can be transformed in `BIT` logic

```
declare @YearStart date = '20140101'
declare @YearEnd date = '20140430'

;WITH D(N) AS (
          SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 
UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
), CM AS (
  SELECT EOM
       = DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(M, u.N + 10 * t.N + 1
               , DATEADD(Y, DATEDIFF(Y, 0, @YearStart), 0)))
       , pMonth = u.N + 10 * t.N
  FROM   D u
         CROSS JOIN D t
  WHERE  u.N + 10 * t.N <= DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart, @YearEnd)
), I AS (
  SELECT ID
       , OpenDate
       , Closedate = COALESCE(NULLIF(Closedate, ''), '99991231')
       , pOpenDate = DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart, OpenDate)
       , pClosedate = DATEDIFF(M, @YearStart
                    , COALESCE(NULLIF(Closedate, ''), '99991231'))
  FROM   Incidents
)
SELECT MONTH(CM.EOM) [Month]
     , Logged = SUM(1 - CAST(pOpenDate - pMonth AS BIT))
     , Received = Count(i.id)
     , Closed = SUM(1 - CAST(pClosedate - pMonth AS BIT))
     , Remaining = SUM(0 + CAST(i.pClosedate / (CM.pMonth + 1) AS BIT))
FROM   CM
       INNER JOIN I ON CM.pMonth
                 BETWEEN i.pOpenDate AND i.pClosedate
WHERE  CM.EOM <= @YearEnd
GROUP BY CM.EOM
ORDER BY CM.EOM;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc2ff/30)</kbd>

The bit logic is base on how the `CAST` to `BIT` works:

- 0 go to 0
- everything else go to 1

based on that (with A and B integer):

- `1 - CAST(A - B AS BIT)` is 1 when `A = B`
- `CAST(A / (B + 1) AS BIT)` is 1 when `A > B` (the `0 +` is to force an implicit cast to `INT` as `BIT` cannot be `SUM`med)

Comment: tried the above query its not giving me the exact Data for all, logged,closed,remainig,received

Comment: i thing its not taking exactly from '20140101 00:00:00' to '20140331 23:59:59'

Comment: Closed function should be incident which are open within the month or previous months but Closed within this month not only which are open and closed in the same month

Comment: Received is Carried Forward incidents + logged in the current month

Comment: and the remaining is Received incidents of the current month - Closed incidents

Comment: please find my update in my question, i already done half of the question by using Union function but for the Remaining and Received still confused how to write the query.

Comment: how can i add the SQL Fiddle here?

Comment: [link] (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abfc1/1/0) find this link as the Received for february is 8 and Remaining 3, March Received 5 and Remaining 2, April Received 3 and Remaining 1

Comment: i need now to get the remaining and received data

Comment: i tried the queries using my Data, the Closed function giving me only the the Closed which are open within the month its not giving the previous months data, the date format that iam using it is 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' i think its affecting the data that i have because the query is fine but iam unable to receive the correct data.

Comment: please find this link which contain the my Data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2549/3/0  . if i changed the "declare @YearStart date = '20140101'" to '20140201' its not give me the data which are logged in the previous months and closed in February

Comment: iam using SSRS and the Data which i select for "@YearStart" and "@YearEnd" are based on month. if i select to provide me report from 2014-01-01 to 2014-1-31 it should give me the incidents which are open in previous months and closed in January. the query which you write is correct but when i select one month it not give me the correct number of closed incidents

Comment: see this link also i added for previous year but iam not getting to correct data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65ef9/2/0

Comment: but it will not give the correct data for the first month of the year "January" as January also contain Data which raised in previous months and closed in January.Is there any other way???

Comment: checked and i got the Data, appreciated your support, thank you very much. you can update your answer.

Comment: Thank you Serpiton, appreciated your support, i will try the second formula also.

Answer (score 0):

Received would be the number of tickets that were opened before the end of the month, and not closed before the start of the month.

```
count(case when OpenDate <= @EndOfMonth and 
                (@StartOfMonth >= CloseDate or CloseDate is null) then 1 end)
    as Received
```

Closed is straightforward:

```
count(case when CloseDate between @StartOfMonth and @EndOfMonth 
                then 1 end) as Closed
```

You should be able to figure out how to calculate the start and end of a month using Google.